# Cannot connect to Coinbase Extension via the @web3-react/walletlink-connector

Tags: reactjs, blockchain, ethereum, coinbase-api

I am trying to connect to the coinbase extension via the wallet link connector's instance, new WalletLinkConnector, but I cannot even get the extension's popup open. I am following the exact tutorial on the official docs. The connection with the metamask works fine but it fails with the coinbase. Here is the screenshot of the error I am getting in console.log
[image: errror]

Here is the connector code I am using

```js
export const Walletlink = new WalletLinkConnector({
  url: "https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/<my-api-key>",
  appName: "demo",
});
```

I am calling this WalletLink via the activate method of the **useWeb3React()**. Any solution will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seems to be some kind of a cache bug yet to be resolved. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71780673/coinbase-extension-popup-requires-remove-the-cache-every-time-for-connection

Answer (score 0):

This maybe happen in non https websites in my experience.

Did you try to connect in SSL website (https)?

Comment: It on the localhost 3000