# Coinbase extension popup requires remove the cache every time for connection

Tags: reactjs, blockchain, coinbase-api

I am having trouble connecting the coinbase wallet in my application and I was wondering if you could help me with this. My issue is that I am using the web3-react(beta) for coinbase connection in my react app.

It requires me to remove the browser's cache and start the development server with the **--reset-cache** flag in order to prompt the extension's popup for the connection every time. After connecting and disconnecting only one time, the extension's popup does not appear.